# C++ memcpy to a malloc'ed memory

Tags: c++, malloc, memcpy

I have the following code and it works well :

```
int Size ;
CString Message ;
BYTE Buffer[256] ;
Message = _T("Some Text") ;
Size = Message.GetLength() * sizeof(WCHAR) ;
memcpy(Buffer,&Message,Size) ;
```

But when i change it to this :

```
int Size ;
CString Message ;
BYTE* Buffer ;
Buffer = (BYTE*) malloc(256) ;
Message = _T("Some Text") ;
Size = Message.GetLength() * sizeof(WCHAR) ;
memcpy(Buffer,&Message,Size) ;
```

And then check the Buffer data, it populated with some random trash bytes

What's wrong ?

Comment: How are you checking the contents?

Comment: @djna I'm sending the content via socket `g_CS.Send(&Buffer,256);`

Comment: I don't know g_CS, but if it takes a pointer, Buffer is already a pointer you don't need &Buffer, just Buffer. You code should work so I am suspicious of how you are using the filled Buffer.

Comment: @djna `int CAsyncSocket::Send(const void* lpBuf, int nBufLen, int nFlags = 0)`

Comment: so you don't need &Buffer, Buffer is already a pointer

Answer (score 4):

CString is not a POD type and cannot be bitwise copied.

It seems you have to switch paradigms from C to C++

From the docs it seems like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx supports a conversion:

```
LPCTSTR raw = (LPCTSTR) Message;
// now memcpy from `raw`
```

Comment: no difference,not just CString I cant copy any other data types such az BYTE or CHAR to malloc'ed memory

Answer (score 3):

`BYTE Buffer[256]` creates an array of 256 `BYTE`-sized elements, regardless of `BYTE`'s size.
`malloc(256)` on the other hand allocates 256 bytes of memory. Try `malloc(256 * sizeof(BYTE))`.

Comment: `sizeof(BYTE)` = 1 so whats the point of this `malloc(256 * 1)` ?!

Comment: If it is really, then in this case it's not a problem indeed, however it's not obvious that sizeof(BYTE) is 1. Another problem is that you copy sizeof(WCHAR) chunks. Again it's not obvious what is the size of WCHAR.

Comment: Who knows maybe in win13 size of WCHAR will be 4 ! but size of a single byte will remain 1 always :D

Comment: Please remember that the only thing that is obvious, is that we all will die :) If you expect help, provide all possible details. Maybe the size of byte will remain one, but that doesn't say anything about a mysterious macro called BYTE of unknown origins. Regarding your other comments in other answers - try printing out the contents to the console, verifying the data after socket transmission leaves too much ground for something else to go wrong.